# The POST method is not supported for route register. Supported methods: GET, HEAD Laravel

Tags: laravel

i am going to make a registation form in laravel when i registered the user and click submit button. i got the error was
**The POST method is not supported for route register. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.**

what i tried so far i attached below.

**Routes**

```
Route::post('register', [RegisterContoller::class])->name('register');
```

**Views**

```
@extends('layout')
@section('content')
  
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Contact Form</div>
        <div class="card-body"> 
        
            <form action= "{{ route('register') }}" method="post">
             {!! csrf_field() !!}   
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class ="form-control"> </br>

            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" class ="form-control"> </br>

            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class ="form-control"> </br>


            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class ="form-control"> </br>


            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success"> 


            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

**Contoller**

```
class RegisterContoller extends Controller
{
    public function create()
    {
        return view('contact.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $input = $request->all();
       Register::Create($input);
       return view('contact.thanks');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Register extends Model
{

    protected $table = "register";
    protected $primarykey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ["fname","lname","email","password"];



    use HasFactory;
}
```

routes images
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any method called register. `store` method is where you call the `Register::Create` method, passing it the input from form.

The route has to be like this:

```
Route::post('/register', [RegisterContoller::class, 'store'])->name('register');
```

EDIT:

Running the following command should work:

```
php artisan route:cache
php artisan route:clear
```

These will clear the routes cache.

Comment: i tried this code same error displayed

Comment: Is the route in the web.php file?

Comment: yessssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

Comment: pls, add an image of your routes

Comment: i added the imagee

Comment: Add '/' before register and run the following command: `php artisan r:l` in console

Comment: same error i added Route::post('/register', [RegisterContoller::class, 'store'])->name('register');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251564/discussion-between-abi-jega-and-alvaro-perez-diaz).